# Expected value obtained in two ways

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Let $X$ has the cumulative density function
\begin{equation}
F_X(x)=1-\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{2}, \quad x>a,
\end{equation}
and $Y$ has the cumulative density function
\begin{equation}
G_Y(y)=1-e^{-y}
\end{equation}
The problem is to find $E(\max(X,Y))$.

**My attempt:**
Way 1:
\begin{equation}
P(\max(X,Y)>z)=1-P(X\leq z)P(Y\leq z)=
\begin{cases}
1-(1-\left(\frac{a}{z}\right)^{2})(1-e^{-z}), &\quad z>a\\
0, &\quad z \leq a
\end{cases}
\\=
\begin{cases}
\left(\frac{a}{z}\right)^{2} + e^{-z}-\left(\frac{a}{z}\right)^{2}  e^{-z}, &\quad z>a\\
0, &\quad z \leq a
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Now,
\begin{eqnarray}
E(\max(X,Y))&=&\int_{0}^{\infty} P(\max(X,Y)>z)dz\\
&=& \int_{0}^{a} dz +\int_{a}^{\infty} P(\max(X,Y)>z)dz \\
&=&a + \int_{a}^{\infty}\left[\left(\frac{a}{z}\right)^{2} + e^{-z}-\left(\frac{a}{z}\right)^{2}  e^{-z}\right] dz\\
&=&a + a + e^{-a}-a^2 \Gamma(-1,a)\\
&=&2a + e^{-a}-a^2 \Gamma(-1,a).
\end{eqnarray}

Way 2:
\begin{eqnarray}
E(\max(X,Y))&=&E(X)+E(Y)-E(\min(X,Y))\\
&=&2a+1-\int_{0}^{\infty} P(\min(X,Y)>z)dz\\
&=&2a+1-\int_{0}^{a} dz-\int_{a}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a}{z}\right)^{2}  e^{-z} dz\\
&=&2a+1-a-a^2 \Gamma(-1,a)\\
&=&a+1-a^2 \Gamma(-1,a)\\
\end{eqnarray}
My question is way 1 is correct or way 2 and why the other one is not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Good news, your expectation for the maximum is correct.

Because $\mathsf P(X\leq z)=0$ when $z\in[0,a]$, then:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\max(X,Y)) &= \int_0^\infty\mathsf P(\max(X,Y)>z)\,\mathrm d z\\&=\int_0^a1\,\mathrm d z+\int_a^\infty \bigl(1-\mathsf P(X\leq z)\,\mathsf P(Y\leq z)\bigr)\,\mathrm d z\end{align}$$

---

Bad news, your expectation for the minimum is in error.

The fact is, $\mathsf P(X>z)=1$ in that domain, so the first term will be different.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\min(X,Y)) &= \int_0^\infty\mathsf P(\min(X,Y)>z)\,\mathrm d z\\[1ex] &= \int_0^a\mathsf P(Y>z)\,\mathrm d z+\int_a^\infty\mathsf P(X>z)\,\mathsf P(Y>z)\,\mathrm d z\\\end{align}$$

---

Good news, everything else looks okay...